# Using str_replace_all() not working on data.table column for unicode apostrophe ("â<U\\+0080><U\\+0099>")

Tags: r, facebook, data.table, stringr

I'm trying to use R to analyse some facebook messages downloaded. Some of the messages have the apostrophe replaced with "â" - I'm trying to replace this using str_replace_all().

As an example, take the following data.table

```
names <- c("Me", "Me", "You", "You", "Me", "You")
content <- c("Iâ<U+0080><U+0099>ve got my party on the 5th", "Hello", "Bears", "Four times four", "what do you want to eat?", "get some music")
date <- c("1/1/2001", "2/1/2001", "3/1/2001", "4/1/2001", "5/1/2001", "6/1/2001")
fbmessagesexample <- data.table(names, date, content)
```

I then try to use str_replace_all

```
fbmessagesexample[, content := str_replace_all(content, pattern = fixed("â<U\\+0080><U\\+0099>"), replacement=fixed("'"))]
```

The first row in content is not being replaced. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please pass a vector for `pattern`.

The following code snippet is resulting in console output as shown below.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

names <- c("Me", "Me", "You", "You", "Me", "You")
content <- c("Iâ<U+0080><U+0099>ve got my party on the 5th", "Hello", "Bears", "Four times four", "what do you want to eat?", "get some music")
date <- c("1/1/2001", "2/1/2001", "3/1/2001", "4/1/2001", "5/1/2001", "6/1/2001")
fbmessagesexample <- data.table(names, date, content)

pattern <- c("â<U\\+0080><U\\+0099>")

fbmessagesexample[, content := str_replace_all(content, pattern, replacement=fixed("'"))]
```

**Console:**

```
> fbmessagesexample
   names     date                      content
1:    Me 1/1/2001 I've got my party on the 5th
2:    Me 2/1/2001                        Hello
3:   You 3/1/2001                        Bears
4:   You 4/1/2001              Four times four
5:    Me 5/1/2001     what do you want to eat?
6:   You 6/1/2001               get some music
```